# Why is my Chromium extensions folder empty?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have two Chromium extensions installed:

[image]

I am on Ubuntu `18.04` and Chromium `Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)`.

However, my extensions folder is empty!

```bsh
$ ls ~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions
```

Where are my extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sdgfsdh:

Open in your chromium this link: chrome://version/

Check the Profile Path directive.

```
Profile Path    /home/user/.config/chromium/Default
```

The normal path is:

```
/home/user/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions
```

But maybe you have another path assigned. Check it.

Comment: Yes, it points to a Snap directory (`/home/username/snap/chromium/1193/.config/chromium/Default`)